# How do I grab the price using Selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium

New to Selenium and Python here.  I am trying to grab the price of the item.

But I get this error:  **'str' object is not callable**.  What am I doing wrong?

[URL of the item](https://www.staples.ca/products/959340-en-dr-pepper-355-ml-cans-12-pack)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url = "https://www.staples.ca/products/959340-en-dr-pepper-355-ml-cans-12-pack"

s=Service('C:/Users/teddy/OneDrive/Desktop/chromedriver.exe')
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--incognito')
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)

driver.get(url)
get_elements = driver.find_element(By.XPATH("//span[@data-product-id='2151359512645'']"))

# print(get_elements.text)
```

Comment: You have added a extra quote at the end of the xpath. It should be `//span[@data-product-id='2151359512645']`.

Answer (score 1):

Answering your question, you have an extra quote at the end of your xpath as [`@pmadhu`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16452840/pmadhu) stated. Moreover you should wait for `<span>` element to be clickable with `get_elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@data-product-id='2151359512645']")))` and it should get rid of an error. Code with imports:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

get_elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@data-product-id='2151359512645']")))
```

Comment: Can you explain how would you know you have to wait for the span element to be clickable?

Answer (score 0):

There's a modal pop-up that you should click on first.

Also, the XPath that you've is `numeric` and it will never be consistence.

Please use CSS over XPath.

**Code :**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url = "https://www.staples.ca/products/959340-en-dr-pepper-355-ml-cans-12-pack"

s=Service('C:/Users/teddy/OneDrive/Desktop/chromedriver.exe')
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--incognito')
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)

driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

driver.get("https://www.staples.ca/products/959340-en-dr-pepper-355-ml-cans-12-pack")

try:
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".Modal__Title+span.icon--close"))).click()
    print('Clicked on close modal pop up')
except:
    pass

price = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.money-details+span"))).text
print(price)
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Output :**

```
Clicked on close modal pop up
$7.29
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by this comment?  "XPath that you've is numeric and it will never be consistence."